# what is the purpose of Makefile in Nis Server

Tags: linux

can anybody tell the use of make file in Nis server please

Answer (score 1):

NIS uses an internal DB format to process and serve information efficiently. But the user edits these as text files. The makefiles contain the commands to update the internal DB after changes to the text files.

For more information on NIS, [see these documents](http://dlc.openindiana.org/docs/osol/20090715/SYSADV5/html/cnis1-25208.html). It's for opensolaris but it's very similar on Linux.